How can I get my code to recognize Leap years using Increments and While True functions
I've recently started an online python course and stumbled upon an exercise that has left me baffled for over a week.
Most of the advice I have gotten have was that I should incorporate increments and loops as a way to check my years and to know which one is a leap year and which is not a leap year.
So: that for every leap year(e.g 2024)/non leap year(e.g 2023) the next one would be (2028)/(2024). But none of the code that I've tried has seemed to give me a pass on the exercise.
I've checked Stack Overflow and found a similar questions that I've tried but did not work (Leap year while-loop).
Please see the question and my code below. You can either give it to me and I'll try and decipher the logic of the code by myself or you can add a little description as to how you did in order for me to better understand the mechanism behind it.
Question:

Please write a program which asks the user for a year, and prints out the next leap year.
Sample output
Year: 2023
The next leap year after 2023 is 2024

If the user inputs a year which is a leap year (such as 2024), the program should print out the following leap year:
Sample output
Year: 2024
The next leap year after 2024 is 2028


My code:
year = int(input("Year: "))
while True:
    if year%4==0:
        if year%100==0 and year%400:
            print(f"The next leap year after {year} is {year+4}")
            break
        elif year%100!=0 or year%400==0:
            print(f"The next leap year after {year} is {year+4}")
            break
        else:
            print(f"The next leap year after {year} is {year+4}")
            break
    elif year%4!=0:
        print(f"The next leap year after {year} is {year+1}")
        break
        year+=1

I've tried reddit, discord and several previously asked questions on this website (Leap year while-loop)
I would really appreciate someone who knows how to do it to show me the solution along with a description of how they got to the answer as I have been stuck on this for a week and havent able to move on. I am just starting off in coding and would like to pursue a career in it therefore I am self learning in it and do not have a tutor or someone I could go to therefore all of your help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

You need to do year += 1 before the loop, so if the user enters a leap year you don't return that same year, you go to the next one.

You need to use a different variable for the year that you increment than the year that the user entered, so your message can contain the original year and the found leap year.
This variable should start with the year after the year the user entered, so that if they enter a leap year you'll go to the next one after that.
And your leap year logic is wrong. When the year is a multiple of 4, you need to exclude some of the century years.
year = int(input("Year: "))
next_year = year + 1
while True:
    if next_year % 4 == 0:
        if not (next_year % 100 == 0 and next_year % 400 != 0):
            print(f"The next leap year after {year} is {next_year}")
            break
    next_year+=1


Hey Barmar thanks alot for taking the time respond to my query. Upon inserting the year 1896 into the code it returns with the message "Make sure that there isn't an infinite loop inside of the your code"

continue was skipping over the next_year += 1 statement. I've removed that.

Barmar Thank you very much it seems to work now! Cheers!
